# Unable to access Radio Button from angular unit tests

Tags: angularjs

I have a radio button in my html form.  I would like to simulate event value from the unit tests. When I try to access using the following initializer for accessing the native elements.

```
let component: UserEditComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<UserEditComponent>;
  let de: DebugElement;
  let el: HTMLElement;
de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('SomeName'));
    el = de.nativeElement;
```

The html file for the control looks like this

```
<ejs-radiobutton id="radio"
            label="My Label"
            value="OEM" name="SomeName"

            (change)="onChangeType($event)"

            formControlName="SomeName"></ejs-radiobutton>
```

I get TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined

Please let know what is the mistake I am doing here.